# How to sort keys in a map based on elements in a list

Tags: java, java-8

I would like arrange/sort elements in a map based the keys available in a list ( order of elements in a list is immutable) such that keys in map and list should be in same order using java.

Data in a map :

```
{grocery=150, utility=130, miscellneous=90, rent=1150,
 clothes=120, transportation=100}
```

Data in a list :

```
[utility, miscellneous, clothes, transportation, rent]
```

Expected Result :

```
{utility=130, miscellneous=90, clothes=120, transportation=100, rent=1150 }
```

Comment: In the david solution, just replace map with finalMap

LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> finalMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
List.forEach(o-> finalMap.put(o, map.get(o));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a sort. 
You want to process the elements by starting from the list.
Supposing that the textual values be String and that the numeric values be Integer, you could do that :

```
Map<String, Integer> finalMap = 
list.stream()
    .collect(toMap(o->o, map.get(o), (a,b)->a, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

or still :

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> finalMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
list.forEach(o-> finalMap.put(o, map.get(o));
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks david

Comment: You are welcome. Good catch on the typo : `map ---> finalMap`

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the map based on the index of occurrence of the *key* of the map in the given list by using a `Comparator` then to preserve the sort order collect it to a `LinkedHashMap` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("grocery", 150);
        map.put("utility", 130);
        map.put("miscellneous", 90);
        map.put("rent", 1150);
        map.put("clothes", 120);
        map.put("transportation", 100);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(
                            Arrays.asList("utility", "miscellneous", "clothes", 
                                          "transportation", "rent"));
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMap 
        = map.keySet()
             .stream()
             .filter(list::contains)
             .sorted(Comparator.comparing(list::indexOf))
             .collect(LinkedHashMap::new, 
                     (linkMap, key) -> linkMap.put(key, map.get(key)), 
                     Map::putAll);

        System.out.println(sortedMap);
 }
```

Output:

```
 {utility=130, miscellneous=90, clothes=120, transportation=100, rent=1150}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the required list of keys and retrieve the values from the `Map`. To keep order, you should use `LinkedHashMap`:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> sort(Map<String, Integer> map, String[] keys) {
    return Arrays.stream(keys).collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key, map::get, Integer::sum, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```